# Does a const array definition with initialization in C require a length parameter?

Tags: c, codevisionavr

```
const int array[]  = {1,2};
const int array[2] = {1,2};
```

Both compile and work with no problems. Is there any difference in these ?

(I use Codevision, but that shouldn't really matter)

Comment: No, the 2 is implicit in the first one, they're the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

The only exception is for the 2nd case if one initialises a `char` array with a string literal and the array's size does not reflect the `'\0'`-terminator, then the latter gets chopped off.

```
char s[] = "alk" // makes s 4 chars wide
char s[3] = "alk" // makes s 3 chars wide
```

For all other types or kinds of initialisation the compiler should warn about a too large initialiser.

If the initialiser is "smaller" then the array, the remaining elements are initialised as if they were defined at globale scope, that is as if they were `static`.

All this is completely unrelated to whether anything in this context is `const` or not.

Comment: You might add that if you have less values than elements to initialize, the remaining are filled with 0.